# Visual Studio 2010 Workflow Error

Tags: development, workflow, visual-studio, state-machine

I have created a simple workflow in VS 2010. What it does is creating a task for a person, when the person changes the task status to "Complete", it logs a message to workflow history.

When I change the status to complete, it says: **"An error has occurred in xxxx (the workflow name)".**

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Collections;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Compiler;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Serialization;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Workflow.Runtime;
using System.Workflow.Activities;
using System.Workflow.Activities.Rules;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions;

namespace WorkflowProject2.Workflow1
 {
 public sealed partial class Workflow1 : SequentialWorkflowActivity
 {
     public Workflow1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

    public Guid workflowId = default(System.Guid);
     public SPWorkflowActivationProperties workflowProperties = new SPWorkflowActivationProperties();

    private void onWorkflowActived(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
     {

    }

    public Guid taskID = default(System.Guid);
     public SPWorkflowTaskProperties taskProperties = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
     private bool taskHasCompleted = false;

    public SPWorkflowTaskProperties taskAfterProperties = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
     public SPWorkflowTaskProperties taskBeforeProperties = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTaskProperties();
     public String taskOutcome = default(System.String);
     public Guid TaskStatusFieldID = new Guid("c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76");  

    private void createTask1_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

        taskID = Guid.NewGuid();
         taskProperties.AssignedTo = "spdev\\lzhang";
         taskProperties.Description = "Please review";
         taskProperties.Title = "Leave application";

    }

     private void completeTask1_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         // Finalize the task:
         taskAfterProperties.PercentComplete = 100;
         taskOutcome = "Completed";
     }

    private void notComplete(object sender, ConditionalEventArgs e)
     {
         e.Result = !taskHasCompleted;    // **(A)**
     }
     private void onTaskChanged1_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
     { 
        string taskStatus = taskAfterProperties.ExtendedProperties[TaskStatusFieldID].ToString();

        if (taskStatus == "Completed")
         {
             taskHasCompleted = true;     // **(B)**

        }

    }

}
 }
```

I have a feeling that there must be some problem with (A) or (B) but I don't know how to fix it. I didn't find any error in the log file in the 14/LOGS folder...

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try debugging it ? You can attach the debugger in VS to the SPTimer process i believe, set a breakpoint in your workflow and triggering it to run.

Comment: Hi Oddmar, when I tried debugging it it said VS cannot debug and asked me to reinstall VS. I reinstalled it but still the same....weird.

Comment: Do you have an option to try and debug with another computer ? I would try that, just in case there is something wrong with your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem! It was because in "Workflow1.cs[design]" (the design view) I didn't specify the TaskID for "completeTask1" in the "Properties box". By default it is "00000000-0000-0000-000000000000", I should have changed it to "taskID".